# Determine here state on current page with JS

Tags: javascript

Im currently setting an LI here state through CSS like this:

```
body.className li.className {styles for here state}
```

However, I want to eliminated having to add new rules in the CSS file every time I add a new page. Instead, I would like to use JS to say [if the body.class is = to the LI.class, then add a class of "here" to the same LI.

Can someone assist with this logic?

Comment: could you specify your title ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do if there is only one class name on the body element:

```
var bodyClass = $(body).attr("class");
$("li").is("."+bodyClass).addClass("here");
```

Comment: using the class attribute of body is what was asked, but needs the remark that it could fail when more than 1 class is present on the body tag.

Comment: In my page, the body can (and in many cases does) have multiple classes. So I would prefer the script first look to see if any class on the body matched a class on the LI. If so, add a class of here to the LI.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying this technique to set the 'active' class on a menu button for example
'here' as in 'you are here now' or 'the current page'?

this can of course be done by Javascript, but I doubt it's the best way.

javascript example: (with help of jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    var bodyId = $('body').attr('id');
    $('#menu li')            // find li tags in the menu list
        .removeClass('here') // remove previous occurance of 'here'
        .find('li.'+ bodyId) // find li with className equals to the body's 'id'
        .addClass('here');   // add the 'here' class to that Li tag.
});
```

**remark** 1 thing I did, was using the body's `id` to check if it is also present as a class on the LI, then I add the 'here' class. (I used the `id` because there could be more than 1 class on the body, then it is impossible to know which one.)

**possible better way:**
you apparently already write the current page as a `class` on the `body` tag (may I assume this is done automatically via your server side code? php? asp? java?...)
if you can write that, then you could add the logical test in your menu as well.

for example,
where you loop over your menu items you could test if that specific menu item is the same as the current page being requested. then print a `here` class on the li. 
and then your css only needs  `li.here { /* current page styles */ }`

Comment: In my page, the body can (and in many cases does) have multiple classes. So I would prefer the script first look to see if any class on the body matched a class on the LI. If so, add a class of here to the LI.

Comment: of course that's also possible, but isn't it easier to give each body the ID of the page instead? then you don't have to loop to all possible classNames?

Comment: Actually, i could be adding multiple "here" states on any given page. Since my main nav and sub page nav in the same section could both have here states. I think this is the initial reason why i was thinking to use an Class. I should be able to modify your code and test. Thanks!

Comment: The code worked great, Thanks! However i modified it to use classes instead of the ID inline with what i stated above. How would i account for when the body has more than one class. I need to find any li's that have one or more classes that match the body. It will not always be an exact 1 to 1 relationship